# Draggable element on scalable container mouse floats away from helper on creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag a div on a scalable element and when I drag it, the mouse seems to float away from helper on creation. Could anyone help me out with this?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6pyreo/) and my code is below of what I've tried.

```
$("div.text").draggable({
    zIndex: 3000,
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: function (e, ue) {
        return $(this).css({
            'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
            '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
            '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
            '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')'
        }).appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

I've also tried this which helps in some during the high `percent`, but still is off as you scale the container smaller.

```
return $(this).css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')'
}).appendTo('body').offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
```

Comment: do you need mobile support?

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with setting the element position based on the mouse position instead of based on the position of the element relative to the mouse position. That, combined with the element scaling down on dragStart are causing it to jump to where your cursor is in the center and then above your cursor since it scales up. You could use `getBoundingClientRect()` to determine the actual position of the element and then set it manually with JS.

```
            var containerBox = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var docBox = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();

            startTop = containerBox.top - docBox.top;
            startLeft = containerBox.left - docBox.left;

            $(this).css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: startTop + 'px',
              left: startLeft + 'px',
              height: containerBox.height + 'px',
              width: containerBox.width + 'px'
            });
```

I didn't try it with your fiddle but it will most likely solve your issues. Also you should use jquery UI resizable widget as well if you are looking for resizability, instead of rewriting it yourself. Also, why is it that you are scaling the element after it is dragged and not before?